# Find the next occurence of an element starting from one specific element

Tags: jquery

How can I find the next `<img>` ocurrence starting from the element #signal taking in account that it can be anywhere in the DOM, not only siblings?

```
<h2 id="signal"></h2>
<p>random text</p>
<p>random text and tags <img /></p>
```

Comment: Next occurrence of *what*?

Comment: An image, edited the post, thanks ;)

Comment: Suppose it's a child of a different branch of the tree, do you still want to find it? E.g. `<div id="a"><div id="b"><p id="signal"></p></div><img></div>` Note how #signal is inside #b; the image is in #b's parent.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I want to go element by element, just like reading the code, and then getting the first image occurrence.

Comment: There's nothing built into jQuery that will do it for you, you have to traverse the tree yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will get the image even it was not sibling :

```
var theImage, getIt = false;
var nextElem = $('#signal').next();

while(!getIt){

  if(nextElem.prop("tagName")!='IMG'){
    if(nextElem.find('img').length == 0){
      nextElem = nextElem.next();
    }
    else{
        theImage = nextElem.find('img');
        getIt = true;
    }
  }

  else{
    theImage = nextElem;
    getIt = true;
  }

}
```

and you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/9du91yr4/